# Joomla: How to assign profile fields after logged in using LDAP authentication and response object

Tags: joomla3.0

Joomla Version: 3.

I have used LDAP plugin to authenticate Users. After successful login I want to set user's profile fields (Joomla's default profile).

I have edited the LDAP plugin code (plugins\authentication\ldap\ldap.php) to populate the $response object with user info from the Active Domain Server. Now, how to use the $response object to populate the Users Profile fields.